Replacing carpet with vinyl floor
I am working on replacing carpet in my guest bedroom. Everything was removed, but when I slide in the new vinyl, they slide into a gap under the skirting board. This is causing more work for us. Is there a better way to install this without removing the skirting board?

I don't understand the question. Are you installing rolled vinyl, or LVP? You don't want it to go under the baseboards?

I'm also unclear on the nature of the problem. Please revise to explain better.

No. You have the requirement of a 1/4" gap around the perimeter to allow for expansion and contraction of the vinyl. The skirting hides the gap. Removing the skirting cuts your installation time in half while allowing you to
properly interlock the planks.
If the floor is uneven, apply a shoe moulding to cover the difference between the overall level of the skirting and the top of the vinyl plank.

Yes.  You want the vinyl (sheet or plank) to go under the baseboards.  If your (OP's) issue is that there's a gap between the bottom of the baseboard and the top of the vinyl (which I'd expect going from carpet to sheet vinyl) you can either remove and lower the baseboards, or simply add some shoe molding or quarter round to the bottom of the baseboards.
